# Detect if string is number or has decimal value in javascript

Tags: javascript, regex

I need users to enter an amount and this may come in different formats like 500 or 500.00. So I need to check if the user has entered a number or a number with two decimal points. SO far I have tried

```
if(/^\d+$/.test(amount) === false || /[0-9]+(\.[0-9][0-9]?)?/.test(amount) === false){
          //valid
}else{
         //invalid
}
```

But so far only the one to check if it is a number is working fine.

Comment: You want to check that either one of the checks pass, right? Change the `false`s to `true`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I guess you are looking for this

```
var pattern=/^\d+(\.\d{2})?$/;
if(pattern.test(amount))
{
          //valid number pattern
}
else
{
         //invalid number pattern
}
```

---

`\d+(\.\d{2})?$` would match 1 to many digits **optionally** followed by two decimal values..

Comment: Save CPU energy: use an assertion instead of capturing: `/^\d+(?:\.\d{2})?$/` ;)

Comment: @meze nice suggestion..but this is too small footprint for any cpu..:)